# Why is there a difference in behavior when the command are piped to bash versus when bash reads the file with the commands?

Tags: bash

Consider this bash script

```
§ cat sample.sh 
echo "PRESS ENTER:"
read continue;
echo "DONE";
```

If I run it this way, the script exits after the first echo without waiting for the read:

```
§ cat sample.sh | bash --noprofile --norc
PRESS ENTER:
```

However, if I run it this way, it works as expected:

```
§ bash --noprofile --norc sample.sh 
PRESS ENTER:

DONE
```

**Why the difference?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first instance, the `read` will absorb `echo "DONE";` as both the script and user input for `read` are coming from `stdin`.

---

```
$ cat sample.sh 
echo "PRESS ENTER:"
read continue;
echo "DONE";
echo "REALLY DONE ($continue)";
$ cat sample.sh | bash --noprofile --norc
PRESS ENTER:
REALLY DONE (echo "DONE";)
$
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add `echo "$continue"` to the end, the issue becomes obvious:

(Also I removed the semicolons since they do nothing.)

```
$ cat test.sh
echo "PRESS ENTER:"
read continue
echo "DONE"
echo "$continue"
$ bash test.sh
PRESS ENTER:
foo
DONE
foo
$ bash < test.sh
PRESS ENTER:
echo "DONE"
```

`read continue` is taking `echo "DONE"` as input since it's coming from stdin